# Need steps to setup AMQP connector in Mule Studio

Tags: mule, amqp

If anyone could provide the steps to setting up an inbound endpoint for an AMQP connector in a mule flow with step 0 being the the point of downloading the zip file from github, I would be most grateful.

There seems to be this assumed knowledge that most people know how to take a zip file from github and somehow make that file available for use in mule eclipse. Do I need to turn it into a  jar file and if so how do i reference that file from the mule project? .. the permutations for a non java programmer seem endless

I have successfully sent events from salesforce to my email via mule eclipse so I get the idea at a very high  level .. but adding a connector has me completely foxed

#### here is the error

ERROR 2012-08-07 00:35:30,833 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp]

#### here is my config

```
<amqp:connector name="amqpConnector" host="localhost"></amqp:connector>

<flow name="test2" doc:name="test2">
    <amqp:inbound-endpoint exchangeName="topic"></amqp:inbound-endpoint>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="relay.jangosmtp.net" port="25" user="xxxx" password="xxxx" to="xxx@xxxx.com" from="xxx@xxxx.com" subject="test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: When you say "in Eclipse" do you mean "Mule Studio"?

Comment: Correct David - my apologies : "Mule Studio". I have watched the 5 part video tutorial and was most impressed with the platform. Unfortunately my java knowledge is limited as is my experience around eclipse. I have absolutely no idea how to get the AMQP connector into my project. All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would try:

- Delete the project from Studio **without deleting the files**
- Maven-ify the Studio project: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/Importing+Maven+into+Studio
- Add the following dependency to `pom.xml`:

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Run `mvn studio:studio`
- Import the project back in Eclipse, which should have the AMQP transport dependencies added to it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help David. "Maven-ify-ing" the project was the  key to getting it to work. For those .Net types with limited java / eclipse / maven experience (like me)  that are interested, I will be posting a detailed set of steps I followed to get a c# producer client to send messages to an inbound AMQP mule connector that then fwds to an outbound smtp connector to eventually appear in your mailbox

Comment: Just to share my experience with this. I tried the steps above for mule-transport-amqp version 3.3.0 and the build kept complaining that it could not download the xsd file from http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/3.3/mule-amqp.xsd. 

It worked fine using version 3.2.1.1 in the pom.xml file and http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/3.2/mule-amqp.xsd in the flow xml though.

Comment: If I am to mavenify my project and add the above dependency, will I get an icon in the Endpoints section of the MessageFlow GUI at all? I had thought that adding non-mulesoft components would be a little cleaner.

Comment: No you won't get a specific icon. Studio has now a direct support for DevKit-built connectors that makes adding new ones seamless. Alas the AMQP connector predates DevKit and is built as a standard core transport, which doesn't have the necessary bells and whistles to be manually loaded in Studio.